# ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[KDSDialogService -> MatDialog -> MatDialog]: NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm doing unit testing on my application. I'm new to testing, so I need your help.

In my application I make a service that uses MatDialog ( KDSDialogService).
I've tried putting many import alternatives, my service or matdialog as providers I have no idea what to do

```
export declare class KDSDialogService {
    dialog: MatDialog;
    private dialogRef;
    constructor(dialog: MatDialog);
    open(componentOrTemplateRef: ComponentType<any> | TemplateRef<any>, title?: string, data?: any, size?: DialogSize, showClose?: boolean): MatDialogRef<any, any>;
    static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<KDSDialogService, never>;
}
```

And in my home.component.spec I import and make the declarations here, but I still get this error.

```
describe('HomeComponent', () => {
   let component: HomeComponent;
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeComponent>;

   beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         declarations: [HomeComponent ],
         imports:[KDSDialogService, MatDialogModule],
  
      }).compileComponents();
   }));

   beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
    
   });

   it('should create', () => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
   });
});
```

[Print of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysGCy.png)

Answer (score 5):

You can mock it like this:

```js
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
//...
    let matDialogService: jasmine.SpyObj<MatDialog>;
    matDialogService = jasmine.createSpyObj<MatDialog>('MatDialog', ['open']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: MatDialog,
          useValue: matDialogService,
        },
```

Comment: I did it the way you said and it still makes the same mistake.

Comment: your `KDSDialogService` is in the imports array rather than the providers. Is that intentional?